# Xamarin first app "javac" exited with code 2. (MSB6006)

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk

I've looked around stack overflow but haven't been able to find an answer. I'm new to Xamarin and I just created my first android app with a template, but I can't build it because I get that error.

[image: Error]

this is where the error takes me:

```html
  <!-- Compile java code -->
  <Javac
    JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
    ClassesOutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\bin\classes"
    TargetFrameworkDirectory="$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)"
    StubSourceDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\src"
    JavaSourceFiles="@(AndroidJavaSource)"
    ToolPath="$(JavacToolPath)"
    ToolExe="$(JavacToolExe)"
    Jars="@(_JavaLibrariesToCompile);@(_InstantRunJavaReference);@(_ReferenceJavaLibs)"
    JavacTargetVersion="$(JavacTargetVersion)"
    JavacSourceVersion="$(JavacSourceVersion)"
```

Build FAILED.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2): warning : Failed to get the Java SDK version. Found java version "9"
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2): warning : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2): warning : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(605,2): warning :  but this does not seem to contain a valid version number.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1914,3): error MSB6006: "javac" exited with code 2.
    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.33

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Comment: Enable Diagnostic level logging in msbuild and get the cmd / full error of what is failing:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: I added the log to the question, I do have the java SDK though. Thanks

Comment: I have the exact problem too. have you found any solution for this yet? @RodrigoArroyo

Comment: @mohammadkamali I actually did. There was some issue with the latest JDK version combined with the latest android SDK. So I downgraded both and it fixed the problem. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @RodrigoArroyo What are your JDK and Visual Studio version?